# Get the last 500 values of php object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, object

I know the PHP end() function exists, but i don't just want the last value of the object, i want the last 500 values.

I have an object with possibly thousands of data and i want to show a graph on my frontend with this data. But only the last 500 values as more than that could slow down the response time too much.

I was thinking of maybe reversing the values of the data object, take the first 500 values and then reverse it back again. This just sounds like too much wasted processing.

I've also tried to first convert the object to an array and then using the `array_slice($array, -500);` and the converting it back to a PHP object and use it in a `foreach`. When i do this, i get the error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

This is the code:

```
$dataArray = array_slice((array) $data, -5);
$data = json_encode($dataArray);
```

Do you have any ideas what i'm doing wrong here or how to do this smarter?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your `$data` object? If it's an object which I'm assuming has string properties, how are you defining "last" 500 values?

Comment: @ShaunBebbers A slice on an array with a single item?

Comment: Reversing isn't such an expensive operation. I'd go for that solution

Comment: $count = 1000;
    $arrValue = [];

    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        array_push($arrValue, $i);

    }

   //print_r($arrValue);

   $n = 500; //wanted last n value
   $arr = array_slice($arrValue, -$n);
   print_r($arr);

Comment: @JonStirling i get my object from this line: $data = $device->data()->get();

Comment: @ShaunBebbers When i try with your line instead, i still get the error: 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Comment: @KiJéy So [converting to an array -> reversing it -> taking the first 500 values -> reversing it back] won't make any performance issues even for frontend? I'm using lavacharts to make a graph of the data.

Comment: I think we need some more information. Use `echo print_r($data, true);` before you declare the `$dataArray` does that tell you that the `$data` variable is an array? I'm confused why you're trying to parse the `$data` variable to an array as you are doing. If `$data` is `JSON`, use `json_decode($data, true);` rather than `(array) $data` as you are doing.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Nakov's answer did exactly what i wanted with the reverse method. Do you still want me to add your requested information?

Comment: @VaryagiViking - no it's fine if you've found a solution, but more information in your questions is helpful to everyone as the correct solution made an assumption about what type of data was held in `$data`.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Yes you're right, I will try to provide more information next time i have ask another question ;) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your `$data` object is a collection of items, you can use the following:

```
$data->reverse()->take(500)->get();
```

or transform your array into a collection

```
collect($data)->reverse()->take(500)->get();
```

Comment: If i use the top line i get 'missing parameters for get operation' but once i remove it, it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $count = 1000;
    $arrValue = [];

    $arrValueMD = [];

    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        array_push($arrValue, $i);

    }

    foreach ($arrValue as $k => &$v) {

        array_push($arrValueMD, $k, $v);
     //  echo "Current value of \$a:$k $v.\n";
    }
     //   print_r($arrValueMD);

    $n = 500;
    $arr = array_slice($arrValueMD, -$n);
    print_r($arr);
```